# How to use to_csv in Pandas with the index in a different position?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have a dataframe that started out with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['orders'] = orders_df.groupby('d')['orders'].count()
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

This outputs as an example:

```
d,orders
2019-10-01,15
```

However, if I try to specify the column outputs, because I don't want the date to be the first entry:

`df[['orders','d']].to_csv('test.csv')`

I receive an error:

`KeyError: "['d'] not in index"`

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: always add reset_index()

Answer (score 0):

You can try convert indexes to column:

```
df['d'] = df.index
```

and then use `reset_index`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```